# How to recover previous version of password from Keychain on macOS

Tags: macos, safari, password, keychain, gmail

Safari suggested to use strong password which I gladly accepted for one of my internet accounts.

Then after I logged in and logged out I forgot that I changed password and used old pass to login back again - it suggested to save it and it basically overwrote the new strong password it stored in keychain, locking myself in position where I cannot recover my account since old password does not work and new strong password is lost.

Is there any way to recover keychain history for recent macOS (12.5+)?

Comment: Do you have a backup?  e.g. Time Machine.

Comment: Does the service you're logging into allow you to reset your password?

Comment: Nope, no backup phone or email was setup on gmail account. Now I have only one session open with gmail that might expire in near future. When I try to set recovery phone / email it asks for password that was lost. Gmail only allows to reset password when recovery email / phone is setup - not my case. No backup was created.

Comment: Lesson learned: Don't trust Apple with anything. They cannot be bothered to make a backup or provide a history for my most important data. I just have been permanently locked out from a very important site, because Keychain updated my password without even prompting me about it. That bug would be annoying enough on its own, but that they don't keep previous passwords after screwing up like this is completely unacceptable.